# Chaining Angular promise rejections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-translate

I have a chained promise and in the case of a rejection for either of the promises, I need to perform an async operation (get the translated error message). As I've already got a chained promise on success, I assume it's not possible to also chain on rejection - I am attempting to simply nest the async calls, but I'm not getting the resolved promise back from `deferred.reject(deferredRejection.promise);` below. Pointers appreciated!

```
login: function(email, password) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  AuthService.login(email, password).then(function(response) {
    var user = {
      'accountToken': response.accountToken,
      'email': response.username,
      'onboarded': response.onboarded,
      'verified': response.verified
    };          
    return SyncStorageService.write(SyncStorageService.storageKeys.user, 
        user);  
  }, function(error) {
    // login failed
    var deferredRejection = $q.defer();
    $translate('ALERTS.LOGIN_FAILED').then(function(translatedValue) {
      deferredRejection.resolve(translatedValue);
    });
    deferred.reject(deferredRejection.promise);
  }).then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  }, function(error) {
    // saving data failed
    var deferredRejection = $q.defer();
    $translate('ALERTS.UNKNOWN').then(function(translatedValue) {
      deferredRejection.resolve(translatedValue);
    });
    deferred.reject(deferredRejection.promise);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Updated Solution:**

Based on the answer below, I was able to re-write the code as follows:

```
login: function(email, password) {
  return AuthService.login(email, password).then(function(response) {
    return {
      'accountToken': response.accountToken,
      'email': response.username,
      'onboarded': response.onboarded,
      'verified': response.verified
    };
  }).then(function(data) {
    return SyncStorageService.write(SyncStorageService.storageKeys.user, 
        data);
  });
}
```

Notes:

- Both `AuthService.login` and `SyncStorageService.write` now reject promises with an `Error` object (e.g. `new Error('ALERT.ERROR_MESSAGE');`), which bubbles up through `login` to the controller (previously was doing the translation at the service level);
- The controller that calls the `login` method has `.then()` and `.catch()` blocks - on a .catch(), the passed `Error.message` is translated and displayed.

Comment: I think you forgot to return from the error .then callback, if you wanted to pass that down the chain.

Comment: Are you trying to ALWAYS resolve even in failure? i'm missing the point of having `var deferred = $q.defer();` rather than using the promise you already have.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't I need to use `var deferred = $q.defer();` so that the results of the final `then` so that the controller can access that data via that promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not really chaining promises, and using [the forgotten promise/deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Making a few assumptions about how you actually want it to behave, and factoring out the calls to `$translate`, then something like the following I suspect is what you're after:

```
login: function(email, password) {
  return AuthService.login(email, password).then(function(response) {
    return {
      'accountToken': response.accountToken,
      'email': response.username,
      'onboarded': response.onboarded,
      'verified': response.verified
    };          
  }, function() {
    return $q.reject('ALERTS.LOGIN_FAILED');
  }).then(function(user) {
    return SyncStorageService.write(SyncStorageService.storageKeys.user, user).catch(function() {
      return $q.reject('ALERTS.UNKNOWN');
    });
  }).catch(function(message) {
    return $translate(message).then(function(translatedValue) {
      return $q.reject(translatedValue);
    });
  });
}
```

The main things to keep in mind are:

- If you definitely want to reject the derived promise, return `$q.reject(error)` from the success or error callback.

  All the error callbacks above do this. The ones after attempted login or saving use the translation key as the error that will be eventually passed to the final `catch` callback. The success callback from `$translate` also does this to transform its resolved promise to a rejected one, so the final catch callback returns a rejected promise, so the calling code gets a rejected promise, and (presumably) shows the translated error to the user.
- If you definitely want to resolve the derived promise, return anything that isn't a promise from he success or error callbacks. The derived promise will be resolved with that value. (This includes `undefined` if you don't have an explicit return value).

  This is what is done above when returning the user `return {'accountToken'....` in the first callback.
- If you want to defer the resolution/rejection of a promise, return another promise from the success or error callback. Then the derived promise will be eventually resolved or rejected in whatever manner this other promise is resolved/rejected.

  This is what's done above when returning `SyncStorageService.write...`, and when returning `$translate(...`.

Comment: Thank you - can't tell you how helpful this was - connected the dots on everything.